# Restrict Micronaut to TLSv1.3 only

Tags: java, security, ssl, micronaut, tls1.3

I can not find anything in the micronaut docs about how to whitelist/blacklist
different Cipher suites. Does anyone know how to do this?

My Goal is to accept only suites included in TLSv1.3.

Also i can not find anything on how to specify CRLs...

Any help would be greatly appreciated ;-)

I have looked through the documentation at https://micronaut.io/,
but i could not find anything regarding CRLs and Cipher suite configuration...